# Join table based on date

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables:

Table A

```
ID | name
---+----------
 1 | example
 2 | example2
```

Table B (`created` field is `timestamptz`)

```
ID | id_table_a | dek  | created
---+------------+------+---------------------
 1 |    1       | deka | 2019-10-21 10:00:00
 2 |    2       | dekb | 2019-10-21 11:00:00
 3 |    1       | dekc | 2019-10-21 09:00:00
 4 |    2       | dekd | 2019-10-21 09:40:00
 5 |    1       | deke | 2019-10-21 09:21:00
```

I need to get records from `Table A` and each records should have the last `dek` from `table b` based on `created`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a lateral join, very often this is faster than using a `select max()`

```
select a.*, b.dek
from table_a a
  join lateral (
    select id, id_table_a, dek, created
    from table_b 
    where b.id_table_a = a.id
    order by created desc 
    limit 1
  ) tb on true;
```

Another alternative is to use `distinct on`:

```
select a.*, b.dek
from table_a a
  join lateral (
    select distinct on (id_table_a) id, id_table_a, dek, created
    from table_b 
    order by id_table_a, created desc
  ) tb on tb.id_table_a = a.id;
```

It depends on your data distribution which one is faster.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . I don't think it really depends on the data distribution.  Assuming the OP cares about performance, both will take advantage of an index on `(id_table_a, created desc, dek)`.  I imagine they will have similar performance in this case, but also would not be surprised if the lateral join were faster.

Answer (score 0):

With a `CTE` returning the joined tables and `NOT EXISTS`:

```
with cte as (
  select a.id, a.name, b.dek, b.created
  from tablea a inner join tableb b
  on b.id_table_a = a.id
)
select t.* from cte t
where not exists (
  select 1 from cte
  where id = t.id and created > t.created
)
```